# Soma de várias listas Python

Tags: python-3.x

Tenho uma recepção de várias listas de tamanhos diferentes e sempre os valores é  '0 e 1'  como sempre estão mudando não consigo escrever o código para somar. Não consigo atribuir essas listas a uma variável, porque recebo elas assim. Eu recebo esses dados maio ou menos assim e preciso somar!

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

soma = somar todos os números e dar apenas um valor

Answer (score 0):

A maneira mais simples que eu consigo imaginar agora é vc utilizar a função `sum` para cada lista

```
resultado = sum([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]) + sum([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1])+sum([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1])+sum([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1])+sum([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]);

print(resultado);
```

resultado:

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
25
```